# Is there a prohibition on stems starting with /g/ in PIE?

Tags: proto-indo-european

Is there a law that prohibits PIE stems starting with what traditionally reconstructed as non-palatal /g/?

So far I encountered with only one stem that the sources consistently reconstruct with this phoneme: ***gloiu̯os*** "clay". Is this stem reconstructed reliably?  Cannot it be a borrowing?

Note that I know about a prohibition on stems starting with "r-".

Comment: Have you ever read a chapter on PIE phonology in any intro textbook, e.g. Fortson 2010, p. 57, at the very bottom? That should help. As for the ban on word-initial r, can you please "refresh my memory"?

Comment: @Alex B. I currently cannot point you exactly to the source, but my impression is that prohibition on initial r- is currently widely recognized. All roots that seemed to contain initial r- are currently reconstructed with initial laryngeal.

Comment: @Alex B. As for example from Fortson, Starling gives the same root as g(')rās-/-ē- For each root with this initial phoneme I encountered different sources gave different reconstructions of the initial phoneme.

Comment: Well, the plain velars are relatively infrequent to begin with (assuming they really existed), so it could be just a statistical fluke if there are no reconstructed roots beginning with *g*. LIV does list some roots with *g-*, though it marks many of them with a question mark.

Comment: What about *gel (cold)?

Comment: @Joël in my dictionaries it starts from palatal k.     celtos cold     celos cover   cels storing room colia̯ hiding place